# Convert from 0.4.17 to 0.6.2

Tags: truffle, mint

I made a conversion from Solidity 0.4.17 to 0.6.2 of a contract that have a MINT option.

The biggest problem here is that I am not sure if this function mint is okay (will return the correct id).

Look:

```
     function mint(string memory _outer, string memory _inner) public payable onlyOwner{
    Filio memory _filio = Filio({ outer: _outer, inner: _inner });
    filios.push(_filio);
    uint _filioId = filios.length - 1;
//    return _filioId;

    _mint(msg.sender, _filioId);
```

The full code are here:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.2;

import 'openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol';
import 'openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/access/Ownable.sol';

contract FiliosToken is ERC721, Ownable {
    
    constructor() ERC721 ("FiliosToken", "FIL") public {
    
}

  struct Filio {
    string outer;
    string inner;
  }

  Filio[] public filios;

  function getFilio( uint _filioId ) public view returns(string memory outer, string memory inner){
    Filio memory _fili = filios[_filioId];

    outer = _fili.outer;
    inner = _fili.inner;
  }

  function mint(string memory _outer, string memory _inner) public payable onlyOwner{
    Filio memory _filio = Filio({ outer: _outer, inner: _inner });
    filios.push(_filio);
    uint _filioId = filios.length - 1;
//    return _filioId;

    _mint(msg.sender, _filioId);
  }
}
```

So, when I try to deploy the truffle return an revert error.

Comment: It appears to be correct. Do you get any error message?

Comment: Hi Ismael, thanks for the answear!

On tests with "truffle test" give em an error that only the owner can mint!

But the first test was to mint and transfer the ownership to my address.

Comment: What does the tests look like? Truffle deploys new contract instances if tests are in separate unit test.

Comment: The tests test all functions, the only function that I get errors are the "mint"

Here the whole contract:

https://github.com/machado-rev/Filio

Comment: There some problems with your project: the contract is named `FiliosToken` but the file is `FilioToken.sol`, it is referenced as `FilioToken` in tests so it loads a .json in build that doesn't match the compiled file. Also your code uses function `tokensOf` from ERC721, but it was removed in OpenZeppelin contracts. I see no problem with code or tests.

Comment: Thanks Ismael, I will check it again! 

Thanks